Why does Member's Mark Frozen cod have 340mg of sodium while other frozen cod is 75-110mg per serving?
I've compared other brands and even some others from Sam's that have nowhere near the sodium.

Welcome new user. Greg, can you please give a link to oe of the "OTHER" examples you mean?

Read the ingredients:

INGREDIENTS: COD, WATER, SALT

The added salt is the source of the extra sodium. Most frozen fish does not have added salt.
Source: https://www.samsclub.com/p/members-mark-pacific-cod-3-lb/prod21001020
Responding to comments, here is an example of frozen cod without added salt. It has only 60mg of salt per 4oz serving, which must come from the fish itself. This is consistent with the USDA nutritional facts for cod fillets.

Does anyone have an example of a frozen cod that does not have salt added?  Surprisingly I could not find one!

It seems to be the case that one serving (115 grams on that label) of natural cod has only about 60 mg of sodium, not the "75-110" mg you mention.
(I had no idea this was the case!)
https://www.calorieking.com/us/en/foods/f/calories-in-fish-atlantic-cod-raw/V2bxhYJtRfacMQb82XQwEw
(select "grams .. 115")
If you're seeing "75-110" on other brands, it is perhaps likely those other brands also add salt.
(You can possibly, but maybe not, learn this from the ingredients labels, depending on the legalities of what they have to reveal.)
If so, the answer to your question would just seem to be that this product simply adds more salt than the others - ?
I've thought of two theories why this could be, ie, answering your actual question "why" does this have more salt than others.

product link:
https://www.samsclub.com/p/members-mark-pacific-cod-3-lb/prod21001020
(1) Note that it happens to be from China. As is commonly known, cuisines in China, Japan and Asia generally use much more salt than in the West. Conceivably, Chinese processors tend to use more salt?
(2) I had a quick review of the prices of similar products at various retailers; this one seems to be basically the cheapest. Is it possible that (in answer to your question) they just add more salt to beef-up the taste since it is (perhaps) lesser quality fish? (Or, just in general, "cheaper food" from processors and fast food joints tends to have more salt added.)

I'm assuming that you figured out that the product mentioned is from China by looking it up? Making that explicit would improve the answer, since as-is, it reads like you're just speculating that it's Chinese, which is not a good look, to put it mildly. If not, then your answer doesn't really have any basis. Beyond that, I'm going ahead and editing out some unsupported generalization and digression - the OP asked about one cod product, not the tendencies of Chinese food processors, and certainly not drugs.

Upon editing, it became apparent that nothing about the country of origin is actually germane here - I assume salt is a listed ingredient on the label (again, making that explicit would improve the answer). If you want to try to generalize about countries of origin, I'd suggest (1) having actual evidence, and (2) doing it somewhere where it's clearly relevant (i.e. probably not this question, unless you do an awful lot of research about frozen cod).

I didn't say anything about photos, and I knew the product was from China. The issue was that you just assumed someone would click through and discover that it said that; the rest of the answer just takes it as a given that the reader knows it's from China. But again: nothing about where it's from is relevant. Please don't undo my edits; I already explained why I made them.
